# A person you have a relationship for only business

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

In a piece of software, what would I call a person you have a relationship for only business in real life. He/she is not your friend and you are **not working in same place**.

For instance, you are freelancer, and someone wants you hire. So what would I call that person?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Client** or **business associate** might do the job.

Comment: Client is ok. But I think *Business Associate* is the same with *Colleague*, isn't it? So my question is about a person you're not working with in the same place. He shouldn't be your colleague. Am i right?

Comment: I'm not sure, Looking up Colleague in OS X's built in dictionary brings up "a person with whom one works, esp. in a profession or business." with no mention of the setting of the 2 individuals.

Comment: I think *colleague* implies that you work for the same employer more strongly than *business associate*. Although without the word *business*, I think *associate* on its own implies even more strongly that you work for the same organisation *and* perform similar roles within it - possibly working together at least some of the time.

Answer (score 3):

In the particular case you cite, they are my *customer*. If I am a salesman, a plumber,  a consultant, or a member of many other professions, they are also called my customer. If the roles are reversed, they might be called my *contractor*.

Comment: sometimes my brain just stops working. I think because of my project. yes, it's my customer :)) Thank you

Comment: When I sell my services to someone, aren't these people my 'clients' and not 'customers'?

Comment: @Irene I personally hear 'customer' used much more in the software industry, but 'client' would be ok too. Searching on Programmer.SE there are [1,338 results for 'customer'](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=customer) and [2,102 results for 'client'](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=client), which is fairly close (but lacking context to be definitive).

Comment: A client is someone you have a working relationship with, so go with client.

Answer (score 2):

*Colleague* is a good alternative, if you do not want to specify the exact nature of the working relationship...in fact, there may not be one at all, just a shared profession or area of expertise/interest.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but it neither suggests working at different places or hiring freelancers.